# What's wrong with my pointer arithmetics?

Tags: c++

I need help trying to figure out why my pointer array is not working. I am incrementing the pointer address and the I.  My console windows is just hanging.

```
int *arr = new int[10];
int i = 0;

while (i < 10){
    *arr = i;  // assign the value of arr to i
    arr++;     // increment the pointer by 1
    i++;       // increment i
}

delete[] arr;
```

Comment: What's _"not working"_ actually? That piece of code looks fine. Your error is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe really obvious but you're deleting arr's values with delete. Otherwise the code is fine.

Comment: Use a debugger and explain what is not working please.

Comment: Please do not edit the corrected code into your question.  It's misleading for anybody who comes across this in future.  I have rolled back to the previous revision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this declaration

```
int *arr = new int[10];
```

pointer arr is initialized by the address of the first element of the dynamically allocated array.

In the while loop

```
while (i < 10){
    *arr = i;  // assign the value of arr to i
    arr++;     // increment the pointer by 1
    i++;       // increment i
}
```

the pointer is incremented.

```
arr++;
```

So after the loop it points beyond the allocated array and this statement

```
delete[] arr;
```

is wrong because pointer `arr` does not now store the original addres of the allocated array.

I think you mean the following

```
const int N = 10;
int *arr = new int[N];

int i = 0;
for ( int *p = arr; p != arr + N; ++p ){
    *p = i++;  // assign the value of i to *p
}

for ( int *p = arr; p != arr + N; ++p ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;

delete[] arr;
```

Comment: So if i do this: int *p = arr;  delete p; that should work?

Comment: no delete arr at the end. p is a working pointer.

Comment: The `delete p` will not work.  The `delete` operator expects a pointer to the first (original) location.

Comment: @runners3431  It will work if at the moment when the delete is used pointer p  has the same value as the original value of arr provided also that you will write correctly delete []p;